# How can I write a code in apex that fires an alert when client selects a specific choices from 2 items

Tags: oracle-apex, multipleselection

I have two items, `P4_oper_type` and `P4_plan` they are both drop down lists
all I want to do is when the client chooses *"Partial Surrender"* from `P4_oper_type` and *"A"* from  `P4_plan`
an alert appears on the page, any other choice that client makes other than the specified conditions nothing happens.

I tried to write this code :

```
function cond(){
var item1 = apex.item("P4_oper_type").getValue();
var item2= apex.item("P4_plan").getValue();

 if (item1.value == "Partial Surrender") && (item2.value == "A") {
  window.alert('omar')
 };
 else null;
  };
```

There is the place where I wrote my code, I don't know if this is the right place or there is something wrong with this code:

[image: code sample]

These are the two items to be selected by client with the condition :
[image: two items to be selected by client with the conditions]

Comment: The value of P4_oper_type is not "Partial Surrender" - that is the display value. Check for the return value instead. Same for the 2nd list of values.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript is invalid in a number of ways (you will be seeing errors in the browser tools console) and is **defining** a function, not **executing** anything.  You may also have other issues in the set-up of your dynamic action that we can't see from your screen shots.

When using dynamic actions you should try to use as little Javascript as possible.  In this case you just need a Javascript expression to define the client-side condition:

```
$v("P8_OPER_TYPE") == "Partial Surrender" && $v("P8_PLAN") == "A"
```

`$v("x")` is a shorter way of writing `apex.item().getValue("x")`

Your dynamic action should look like this:

[image]

Then for the action you don't need Javascript, just an Alert action:

[image]

If for some reason you really needed to write a Javascript function and call it from the dynamic action, you would define the function in the page "Javascript Function and Global Variable Declaration" section like this:

```
function cond() {
  var item1 = $v("P8_OPER_TYPE");
  var item2 = $v("P8_PLAN");

  if (item1 == "Partial Surrender" && item2 == "A") {
    alert('omar')
  }
};
```

And call it from the dynamic action like this:

```
cond();
```

Comment: It Worked fine , thank you very much for your time and effort.